# How to fix nestjs-typegoose dependency problem in a correct way without --legacy-peer-deps?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I have created a new NestJS project and wanted to install [nestjs-typegoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-typegoose). In the process, I got the following error:

```
npm i nestjs-typegoose
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: top-api@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @nestjs/common@8.4.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/common
npm ERR!   @nestjs/common@"^8.4.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @nestjs/common@"^6.10.1 || ^7.0.0" from nestjs-typegoose@7.1.38
npm ERR! node_modules/nestjs-typegoose
npm ERR!   nestjs-typegoose@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I accept an incorrect and potentially broken dependency resolution when I use "--legacy-peer-deps" according to this message.

This looks to me like a bad solution that can or will lead to problems later. Do I understand it right my installed @nestjs/common is too new for nestjs-typegoose? Would a downgrade to version 7 of @nestjs/common be enough and is it recommended or will this create even more conflicts with other new modules? In this situation, is it better to install one package with --legacy-peer-deps or downgrade another one? (Please, see UPDATE below).

**UPDATE:**

I tried with --legacy-peer-deps and got an MongoParseError:

```
MongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported
```

To make the error disappear, the following line must be commented out in the mongo options file:

```
//useCreateIndex: true,
```

If I downgrade to version 7 instead, another error occurs:

```
Unsupported engine { npm WARN EBADENGINE package: '@angular-devkit/schematics-cli@0.1102.6'
```